# Why would my WP plugin work for one person and not another on the same system?

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

My cousin and I built a WordPress plugin for CoursePress that will take in a list of email addresses, and add them as users/students into a course.

We have used this plugin on multiple occasions without fail, but one client of ours told us that the plugin would not work for them. I have screen shared and verified that they are using the plugin correctly.

The plugin takes in a .csv file in "Email,FirstName,LastName,CompanyName" format, adds users based on that data, adds those users as students to selected course, and prompts you to download a new .csv file that will contain user names and passwords from created users.

You can see the code [HERE](https://github.com/deandavis182/CP-Import-Panel)

My initial thought was that Windows and Mac/Linux save .csv files with different line endings, so maybe that is the problem, but I sent this person a file that I saved through my MacBook and instructed to not open the file but to just try to use it in the plugin to see if it works. Still nothing.

I have made some edits in the uploads.php file to try to narrow down the problem, but I am not making any progress.

In the edits below, I am trying to see if the "uploaded_file" post variable is empty, and if it is, to tell me it is. The current error my client is having is "There was an error during file validation!". I am pretty sure his error should be reading the $ers variable from below, but I cannot get it to give me that error when I submit the form without a file.

Can anyone help me?

```
<?php
function wp_mail()
{
    // Do nothing!
}

error_reporting(0);

require_once('../../../../wp-config.php');
include 'gen-file.php';

//Posted files

$files = $_FILES["uploaded_file"];
if (empty($files)) {
    $ers = 'The file was not sent with the form!';
  }

$post = $_POST;
//Imported users CsV
$impUsers =  array(array( "Username", "Password", "email" ),);


$file = checkFile($files);


if($file){
    $ID = getCid($post);
    $tmpname = $file['tmp_name'];
    //Convert CSV to array
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($tmpname));
    //Remove first row in CSV Array
    $csv = array_splice($csv, 1);
    //Create Users
    $Users = createUsers($csv);
    //Add users to course
    $students = AddAsStudents($Users,$ID);

    convert_to_csv($Users);
    }else{


    echo 'There was an error during file validation! </br>';
    echo $ers;
        }
```

Comment: Maybe some other plugins, or WP settings are interfering with your own plugin?

Comment: That was my first thought, but I can login as my admin user, run the plugin, and everything will work fine. My client can login to the same system, under the same user, and get no results. The only difference I can see is that he is using a different OS than me, but if that were the case, the plugin wouldn't work for other Windows users, which it does.

Comment: What happens if you log on your system, but as his user?

Comment: When I log in as his user, the plugin works just fine. When he logs in to my user account on that system it will not work for him but still works for me.

Comment: what does `checkFile()` do?

Comment: Obviously that is returning false for him and not you.

Comment: @BizzyBob checkFile validates that the file is not empty and its extension is .csv. you can see the code at the github link

Comment: so this check is failing for him: `if (($ext == "csv") && ($files["type"] == "text/csv") && ($files["size"] < 350000))`

Comment: Echo out those values and see what they are.  perhaps "type" is different for him.

Comment: `$_FILES['userfile']['type']`
The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information.This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.

Comment: Is he using a different browser than you..?

Comment: @BizzyBob He is using the same browser as me, Google Chrome. I have made your suggested edit below, and emailed him to try the plugin again. I will let you know his results. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your `checkFile()` function.  The function is using the `$_FILES['userfile']['type']` as a part of validation.  However, as stated in the documentation:

> **$_FILES['userfile']['type']** - The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information.This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.

Therefore, different browsers may send different values or no value at all, so you can't depend on it.

You can probably just remove that from your check on this line:

```
if (($ext == "csv") && ($files["type"] == "text/csv") && ($files["size"] < 350000))
```

and use:

```
if (($ext == "csv") && ($files["size"] < 350000))
```

Comment: This was the problem. He is using the same browser as me, but this edit made it start working for him. THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP:)!!!